# "Apk Installation failed: ANDROID_BOOT_FAILURE" when installing an APK

Tags: installation, apk, bluestacks

I am trying to install Google Play Store 6.0.5 on my PC through BlueStacks APK handler. It shows "Installing APK", but after sometime it shows

> Apk installation failed: ANDROID_BOOT_FAILURE

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: While it's not the same problem, [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/showbox/comments/3j1yos/apk_installation_failed_install_failed_invalid_apk/), try installing `PackageFileInvalidIssueResolver.apk` first.